# how to insert <interger,string,string> in map (3 inputs) in java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, treemap

I have an input that is given below. How can I insert these inputs in a map, `HashMap` preferrably.

```
{1,"abc","a"} {200,"xyz","b"} {1,"ab","c"} {12,"fgh","d"}
```

Integer being the key and remaining are values.

Comment: What is your mapping suppose to look like? What is key and what is value? Is your mapping `<Integer,String> -> <String>`? Or maybe it is mapping of `<int,string,string> -> <somethingElse>`? If you don't have mapping there maybe consider using Set instead of Map?

Comment: That depends on how the fields a related to each other. Can one of them (or a combination of several of them) be considered as the key?

Comment: Your question is poorly specified. Maps have a key/value relationship. Edit your post to indicate what should be the key and what should be the value.

Comment: Integer being the key and remaining are  string values

Comment: @Pshemo but how can I do that....

Comment: "but how can I do that...." It depends on what you want to achieve. Lets take a look at key `1`? At start it contains `"abc","a"` value, but then you try to set it to `"ab","c"`. What should happen here? Should `"abc","a"` be replaced with `"ab","c"`? Or maybe you want to store both `"abc","a"` and `"ab","c"`?

Comment: In my program replacing "abc","a" with "ab","c" is required after execution of some code

Comment: In that case probably simplest way would be creating your own class like `Pair` which will store data like `"ab","c"` or `"abc","a"` and simply place new `Pair` with data you want it to have. So your map can look like `Map<Integer, Pair>` or even `Map<Integer, Pair<String,String>>` if you would like to make Pair generic class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add integer value in hasmap as key and other 2 values in list and then add this list to hashmap as key value

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<Interger, Object>();
List<String> maplist1=new ArrayList<String>
            maplist1.add("abc");
            maplist1.add("a");
            map.put(1, maplist1)
           // otherwise clear maplist
           List<String> maplist2=new ArrayList<String>
            maplist2.add("xyz");
            maplist2.add("b");
            map.put(200, maplist2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that doesn't fit to HashMap idea. You can use one of following:

- `Map<Integer, List<String>>`
- `MultiHashMap` of [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html)
- `Multimap` of [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)